# Automationg AdvancedRestClient Extension for chrome

Tags: web-services, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am trying to automate AdvancedRestClient extension for Chrome to test webservice.
I am able to start the Extension and send request. But I am not able to get any response.

```
public class WebServices {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Start the driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","$PATH_TO_DRIVER");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("load-extension=C:/Users/$username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/3.1.7_0");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //Start the extension
        driver.get("chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/RestClient.html");

         try {
             Thread.sleep(10000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         //Get the authentication field and set authentication
         WebElement authField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='appContainer']/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/section[1]/textarea"));
         authField.sendKeys("$SET_AUTORIZATION")

         //Get the reqestURL field and enter request
         WebElement requestField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='appContainer']/div/div/div/div[2]/input"));
         requestField.clear();
         requestField.sendKeys("$REQUEST");

         authField.click();

         //Click on send button
         WebElement sendButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='appContainer']/div/div/div/div[7]/div/button[2]"));
         sendButton.click();        
    }
}
```

The above steps work fine when I do it manually. But script does not generate any response.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Automating a browser to test a web service is not the most reliable or efficient way.

You should instantiate a HttpClient in your test instead a Webdriver instance.  This will allow you to make REST calls directly and interogate the response in the same way you would assert via WebDriver.

This approach will take milliseconds rather than seconds to run a test. Also, it can run anywhere without the need to install Chrome or Webdriver

Comment: Can you share any docs or related to the method you mentioned above. Also I want to know why no response is generated. Manual is working, script fails